# Storing an object in the hashMap after converting it to a string

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a question ,
 what about if we define the hashMap to receive a string key and string value but for some reason we need to store an abject as a value after converting it to a string (obj.toString())
in this example if i traverse the hashMap and i need to access to one if its fields , i could not because it is converted to a string , What i s the solution for it ?  thank you

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMapObj = new HashMap<String, String>();

        hashMapObj.put("hil", "aii");
        hashMapObj.put("hil1", "ai1");
        hashMapObj.put("hil2", "ais2");
        hashMapObj.put("hi3", "aisi3");
        hashMapObj.put("hil4", "aii4");

 Employee obj = new Employee(1, "Bill Hill ", 7);
         int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7};

        hashMapObj.put("emp1", obj.toString());
        hashMapObj.put( Integer.toString(1) , obj.toString() );
        hashMapObj.put("arr" , Arrays.toString(arr));
  for(HashMap.Entry< String , String> x : hashMapObj.entrySet()){
            String  key   = x.getKey();
            System.out.println("key ===> "+ key);

            System.out.println("j ===> " + hashMapObj.get("1"));
             Object e = (Object) hashMapObj.get("1");

             System.out.println(e);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using  `HashMap<String, String>();` use  `HashMap<String, Object>();` and do not convert your objects using the toString() method. If you have done this you will always get an Object if you use get. The Object can then be easily passed to the system println method.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the solution for it?

Two solutions.

The first solution is to not do it in the first place.  Store the objects themselves as the values; i.e. as a `Map<String, YourClass>`  This is the simplest solution, and the most computationally efficient one.

The second solution is more work to implement:

1. Make sure that your define the `YourClass.toString()` method so that encodes all information that would be needed to reconstruct the object.  This typically includes the values of the object's fields.  The string representation needs to be unambiguous, and should be easy to parse.
2. Write another method; e.g. `static YourClass fromString(String s) {...}` that you can use to parse the `toString()` output, and reconstruct the object from it.

You could use JSON as the string representation, and a JSON binding library such as GSON or Jackson to do the object <-> string conversions.

---

Note that this:

```
YourClass y = (YourClass) map.get("1");
```

won't work.  You cannot cast a `String` to `YourClass`.  You need to write some Java code to recreate a `YourClass` instance from a `String`.